# Is there any way to find all untagged files in a folder in OS X?

Tags: macos, tags

I have a folder that contains several thousand images which I'd like to add metadata to using [Deep](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/deep/). Unfortunately, Deep doesn't look like I can filter my folder by which photos DO NOT have tags, so I'm looking for alternative ways of doing it.

Is there anyway to use Spotlight (or something similar) to give me a list of files that do not have any tags? Then I could use something like [Tagit](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/tagit/index.html) to do the manually tagging in smaller bunches, which would make Deep far more useful to me...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the Finder.
Choose "other" from the dropdown menu and choose the "Raw Query" option.
Then type the following:

> kMDItemOMuserTags != '*'

[image]

[source](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/07/25/advanced-spotlight-queries-in-the-mac-gui/)

Comment: Note for anyone who finds this now: the proper search in modern versions (10.10.5) seems to have changed to `kMDItemUserTags != '*'`